# share image and text not working at all

Tags: android, image, text, android-intent, share

I am working at sharing some info with an image from a resource. Here is the code I am using:

```
case R.id.menu_share: 
            //create the send intent  
            Intent shareIntent =  new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);  

            //set the type  
            shareIntent.setType("image/png");  

            //add a subject  
            shareIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT,   
             "CAR EXAMPLE");  

            //build the body of the message to be shared  
            String shareMessage = "An app...";  

            //add the message  
            shareIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, shareMessage);  

            //add the img
            shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse("android.resource://com.car.pack/drawable/" + Integer.toString(R.drawable.log)));               

            //start the chooser for sharing  
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent,"Share"));  
        break;
```

The problem is that in my example I am trying to share a TEXT+IMAGE from a resource. So, when I share with GMAIl app works perfect, but with the others app wich appears in the intent occurs:

- Whatsapp : Only send the image, the text not.
- SMS: not appears the text and the image.
- email app from mobile (sony ericcson Arc S): break the app
- Facebook: only share the image, the text no.
- Bluetooth: I don´t test yet

So I think that the problem was on the text... or I don´t know, if anyone can help me...

THANKS!!!

Comment: WhatsApp and Facebook ignore the EXTRA_TEXT part https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/332619626816423/

Answer (score 0):

Use `shareIntent.setType("*/*");` .

Also try changing `ACTION_SEND` to `ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE` which specialized for delivering multiple data.

Check [here](http://developer.android.com/training/sharing/send.html) for more details.

Comment: Hi thanks... but doesn´t work at all. Now the changes: WHATSAPP doesn´t share nothing when I press a person to share de info, it go back to the app and nothng send. SMS now works I can share the text. The DEFAULT EMAIL APP breaks (maybe sony bugg). FACEBOOK now do somerthing extrange with 3 posibilities of sharing (upload a video, what I am doing now to post and share the text only).

Comment: ooh if I change what you said, now it doesnt appear the option of sharing with Whatsapp and Facebook. And more, the GMAIL app, the sms and BT app crashes.